# Making lex to read UTF-8 doesn't work

Tags: c, xml, parsing, utf-8, lex

I wrote an xml parser that parses ASCII files, but I need now to be able to read UTF-8 encoded files. I have the following regex in **lex** but they don't match UTF-8. I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
utf_8       [\x00-\xff]*
bom         [\xEF\xBB\xBF]
```

then:

```
bom             { fprintf( stderr, "OMG I SAW A BOM"); return BOM;}
utf_8           { fprintf( stderr, "OMG I SAW A UTF CHAR", yytext[0] ); return UTF_8;}
```

I also have the following grammar rules:

```
program 
: UTF8 '<' '?'ID attribute_list '?''>' 
root ...
```

where `UTF8` is:

UTF8

```
: BOM           {printf("i saw a bom\n");}
| UTF_8         {printf("i saw a utf\n");}
|               {printf("i didn't see anything.'\n");} 
;
```

It always comes up with `i didn't see anything`, my parser works for ASCII files, that is when I copy paste the XML UTF-8 file in a empty document.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is a trimmed .l file for reference:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
int lines = 1;
%}

utf_8       [\x0000-\xffff]*
bom         [\xEF\xBB\xBF]
whitespace  [ \t]
ev          (.|{bom})
ev1         (.|{utf_8})
%%
{whitespace}    { fprintf( stderr, "%s", yytext );}
\n              { fprintf( stderr, "%s%d ", yytext, lines++ );}
.               { fprintf( stderr, "{TOKEN:%c}", yytext[0] ); return yytext[0];}
bom             { fprintf( stderr, "OMG I SAW A BOM"); return BOM;}
utf_8           { fprintf( stderr, "OMG I SAW A UTF CHAR", yytext[0] ); return UTF_8;}
%%

void error( char *message )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Error: %s\n", message );
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: *Exactly which* "lex" are you using?  Some can do characters with the high byte set and some can't, some are strictly byte-oriented and some work on codepoints, etc.

Comment: Also, a complete `.l` file would be appreciated.

Comment: @Zack c  `flex' version 2.5.35

Comment: Okay, what you appear to be trying to do *should* work with `flex`.  I can't help any more without a complete flex input file, though.

Comment: @Zack I Just added a trimmed .l file.

Comment: Why you don't use `\X` ?

Comment: @stackoverflow I'll give it a shot in a second. Thanks.

Comment: @stackoverflow I changed `utf_8 [\x0000-\xffff]*` to `utf_8  [\X]*` but still came up with `didn't see anything`

Comment: Ignore @stackoverflow.  `\X` is not a feature of flex.

Comment: @stackoverflow is the trimmed file ok?

Comment: Flex doesn't support any of the alternatives you're pushing either, @stackoverflow.

Comment: @stackoverflow I tried time a long time ago, didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, this is your problem:

```
utf_8       [\x0000-\xffff]*
bom         [\xEF\xBB\xBF]
```

There are two problems here.  First, Flex doesn't actually understand Unicode.  It works on *bytes*.  So you need a regex macro that matches any valid UTF-8 *byte sequence*. http://keithdevens.com/weblog/archive/2004/Jun/29/UTF-8.regex has a regular expression that does that, which is not terribly hard to convert to Flex syntax (see below).  Second, the square brackets in your BOM macro are making it match any *single byte* with value EF, BB, or BF, not the *three-byte sequence* EB BB BF which is what you want.

(Incidentally, UTF-8 files are *not* supposed to have byte order marks, although many do anyway.)

Here is a complete Flex input file that does more or less what you appear to have been trying to do:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

bom     \xEF\xBB\xBF
white   [ \t]

u2a     [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]
u2b     \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]
u3a     [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}
u3b     \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]
u4a     \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}
u4b     [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}
u4c     \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}

utf_8   {u2a}|{u2b}|{u3a}|{u3b}|{u4a}|{u4b}|{u4c}

%%

{white}     { putchar(' ');  }
\n          { putchar('\n'); }
{bom}       { putchar('B');  }
{utf_8}     { putchar('u');  }
[\x21-\x7e] { putchar('.');  }
.           { putchar('^');  }
```

Comment: Does this match any valid UTF-8 byte sequence, or is it only an example, because I still get the message `syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting`

Comment: What I wrote was not a complete lex input file.  I will edit in a complete input file that actually works.

Comment: did you try running this on UTF8 Encoded file? I am still getting undefined messages with your code? I am guessing I am supposed to add the encodings for the characters I am missing?

Comment: If the above file is `test.l`, then `flex -8 -o test.c test.l; gcc test.c -lfl` gives me no syntax errors, and the result appears to work correctly on UTF-8 input.  (I tested it casually, not thoroughly.)  Exactly what command gives you the syntax error message?

Comment: it stops on the first character from the document I am testing, which I am sure is an XML (file -bi testFile says its XML), it gives me no compilation errors. Where are you getting your test file from.

Comment: My test file was just a .txt file I had lying around that happened to have a few UTF-8-encoded quotation marks in it.  But - you ran *my test program* on your XML file and it gave you that syntax error message???  I don't know any way for my test program to produce that message.

Comment: never mind it did work on your code, I think what is confusing it is that my yacc file I have 'char' in my rules for example '<' for the start of the nodes, I guess I would have to change those to tokens. Thanks for all the help.